# I have aproblem with the digital ocean wordpress site

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, prompt

I have aproblem with the digital ocean wordpress site.The site uses the woocommerce plugin as the base for the site functionality. My sitye is hosted in the digital ocean droplet

I installed the wordpress by migrating the whole files from the local to online using the FTP. Now on every page load the site prompts the pop up with the following message.

**"A username and password are being requested by http://107.170.xx.xxx. The site says: "Please login to your droplet via SSH for login details."**

On disabling the woocommerce plugin it won't prompts the popup. But I want the woocommerce plugin in my site which is the base for the site. can anyone please help me with this.

Answer (score 3):

Try this. (This is from Digital Ocean site) [Link here](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/articles/one-click-install-wordpress-on-ubuntu-13-10-with-digitalocean)

Removing the Additional Apache Password Prompt for Admin Areas
Often, after you have completed the installation steps, you'll want to remove the Apache-level password prompt that greets you each time you try to log into the administrative portion of the site. While it can be an additional layer of security, many users feel comfortable relying on WordPress's own authentication mechanisms.

Note: You should not remove this authentication until after you have completed the initial installation. Otherwise, anyone connecting to your domain name or IP address can configure WordPress or access the administration files to change your settings.

To remove the additional password prompt, you'll need to log into your VPS instance through SSH as we demonstrated above. Once logged in, you need to update the main Apache configuration file. Open it as root with your text editor:

```
nano /etc/apache2/apache2.conf
```

Inside, you need to find the section that deals with the "/wp-admin/" section. It should look like this:

```
<DirectoryMatch ^.*/wp-admin/>
    AuthType Basic
    AuthName "Please login to your droplet via SSH for login details."
    AuthUserFile /etc/apache2/.htpasswd
    Require valid-user
</DirectoryMatch>
```

This entire section can be commented out by placing the "#" character before each line, like this:

```
#<DirectoryMatch ^.*/wp-admin/>
#    AuthType Basic
#    AuthName "Please login to your droplet via SSH for login details."
#    AuthUserFile /etc/apache2/.htpasswd
#    Require valid-user
#</DirectoryMatch>
```

Once this is complete, you can restart Apache for your new changes to take affect.

```
service apache2 restart
```

This should remove the additional password prompt from the administrative areas, which is usually okay since WordPress itself can handle authentication.